# Не простые вопросы о языке C#

Tags: c#

Был на собеседовании и завалился. Теперь пытаюсь постепенно забить пробелы в знаниях - осталось немного вопросов, которые я не могу решить сам, поэтому прошу помощи:
Есть запакованная структура, как изменить значение поля структуры, при этом не распаковывая её?
**UPD1:**
Вопрос на собеседовании который я тоже к сожалению завалил и не смог найти адекватного ответа за пару дней, может кто либо из вас знает :
Есть метод в котором много строк кода (100 например), в конце выполнения метода выбивает исключение, как сохранить те данные (ту работу которую проделал данный метод) до исключения ? 
Буду признателен если хотя бы дадите совет куда "копать" !

Comment: Это вопрос на позицию джуниора? Нафиг такую компанию, им нужен не менее чем Джеффри Рихтер.

Comment: @VladD да, это на джуниора, меня просто там разорвали такими подковыристыми вопросами что я просто потерял смысл жизни ... Теперь буду разбирать то что помню на чём завалился !

Comment: @Aleksanders: На джуниора вопрос полностью неадекватный. С одной стороны, конечно, новые знания никогда не помешают, но не расстраивайтесь по поводу своего уровня: знать такие тонкости джуниор не обязан. Хорошо, что вы знаете чем отличается value type от reference type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Через интерфейс

```
void Main()
{
    var o = (I)new A();
    (o).Inc();
    (o).Dump();
}

interface I
{
   void Inc();
}

struct A : I
{
    public int f;
    public void Inc()
    {
       f++;
    }
}
```

выведет f = 1.
Код (нету unbox):

```
IL_0001:  ldloca.s    01 // CS$0$0000
IL_0003:  initobj     UserQuery.A
IL_0009:  ldloc.1     // CS$0$0000
IL_000A:  box         UserQuery.A
IL_000F:  stloc.0     // o
IL_0010:  ldloc.0     // o
IL_0011:  callvirt    UserQuery+I.Inc
IL_0016:  nop         
IL_0017:  ldloc.0     // o
IL_0018:  call        LINQPad.Extensions.Dump
```

Comment: Круто, не знал, что интерфейсы не распаковывают объект.

Comment: @VladD между прочим именно этот способ описан у Рихтера. Видимо в той конторе на джуниора как раз его и ищут

Comment: Рихтер - это просто "стандартная книга" по .нет. Может они считают что все кто его знают наизусть - про.

Answer (score 7):

Поскольку по первой части вопроса о запакованной структуре уже ответили, скажу пару слов по второй части.

Честно говоря, не очень понятна формулировка **"как сохранить те данные (ту работу которую проделал данный метод) до исключения ?"**. Не слишком ясно, что понимается под "сохранить работу".

Очень похоже на то, что собеседовавший вас человек дал вам изначально неправильную задачу. И дело вот в чем. Если по-хорошему, то функции/методы должны быть чистыми. То есть выполнять одну задачу, и не делать сразу несколько дел. Поэтому если метод при вызове выбрасывает исключение, то эта единственная задача не может быть выполнена. Однако в вопросе речь идет о некой "работе", результаты которой нужно "сохранить", несмотря на выброшенное исключение. То есть получается, что этот чудо-метод выполняет несколько задач, одна из которых была выполнена, а другая нет. Однако наличие таких методов, которые как  Юлий Цезарь которые занимаются сразу несколькими делами - признак дурной архитектуры. А учитывая, что сама формулировка вопроса говорит о методе с сотней строк кода (для метода это много), становится очевидно, что сам метод нужно рефакторить и разбивать на несколько маленьких. А уже каждый из этих методов может что-то там делать, или кидать свои исключения, если это "что-то" сделать нельзя.

Ну и пару слов по сабжу. В силу размытости формулировки вряд ли можно стопроцентно угадать, что от вас хотел собеседовавший. Очевидно, что исключение необходимо обрабатывать, поэтому код, способный его сгенерировать, следует завернуть в блок try, а в catch описать логику реакции на исключение. Возможно, что он хотел услышать от вас что-нибудь про использование секции finally (хотя ее обычно не раздувают на сотню строк)

Так или иначе есть ощущение, что человек, собеседовавший вас, не гнушается говнокодством

Comment: @DreamChild Спасибо вам за ответ ! Меня там конечно опустили жестко, даже не знаю толи я дебил или надо мной просто прикололись но вопросы были очень заковыристые как для меня ...

Comment: >Меня там конечно опустили жестко, даже не знаю толи я дебил или надо мной просто прикололись но вопросы были очень заковыристые как для меня

Возможно, вы просто промахнулись с выбором. Расскажите подробнее, что спрашивали помимо этих вопросов, что за вакансия, кого и почем ищут.  Только желательно без выражений типа "опустили жестко", мы же с вами культурные люди, не так ли?

Comment: @DreamChild, Хорошо !
Вакансия была Джуниор Шарп Девелопер !
Пришел в офис, там 4 человека и начали проверку моих знаний :
Вопросы что помнью :
1. Напишите свою реализавцию ЛинкедЛиста ибо нам интересно знать как вы понимаете всё это изнутри - 20минут времени.
2. Есть сторонний класс, в нём есть приватный метод, вы наследуете этот класс в своём классе, как вам вызвать этот приватный метод ? - "10" мин. времени.
3. Что собой представляет атрибут на «физическом уровне»?
4. Как получить все возвращаемые значения при вызове цепочки делегатов?

Comment: 5. Вызов делегата асинхронно. Чем делегат может быть удобней для асинхронного вызова чем Thread или ThreadPool?   
Очень много было листов с кодом где нужно ответить каков результат или указать на ошибку ...

Comment: @Aleksanders по моему скромному мнению из этих вопросов  только один про LinkedList можно давать джуниору, поскольку это базовая теория алгоритмов и структур данных, и по идее это должен уметь каждый выпускник профильного вуза (ну и вообще начинающий программист). А вот что касается остальных, то они явно переборщили. Второй и третий вопрос судя по всему затрагивают тему рефлексии, что джуниору знать, конечно, можно, но не обязательно. Ну а 4 и 5 вопросы для джуниора  - это вообще глупость по-моему. Тем более, что это знания по конкретному языку, что несколько нечестно

Comment: По поводу 2: вам _не должно_ хотеться вызвать приватный метод. На то он и приватный, в конце-концов. Код не должен опираться на подробности чужой реализации.

По поводу 3: подробности физической реализации я не знаю, и мне никогда не было нужно. Думаю, что никому не нужно, нужно знать лишь семантику. Если программисты в этой компании думают не так, я бы не советовал туда идти.

Comment: Ну а метод с листами кода - в принципе, конечно, можно, но вообще несколько некрасиво, поскольку человека заставляют работать компилятором, чего он делать не должен

Comment: @DreamChild, Спасибо вам большое за комментарии и ответы ...

Comment: кстати соглашусь с @VladD по поводу 2 и 3. Хотя, мне показалось, что под "атрибут на «физическом уровне»" они подразумевают, что это, дескать, класс. Хотя, если речь шла именно о подробностях его реализации в CLR, то это уж совсем ниже пояса.

Answer (score 4):

Ну, самый прямой путь — через reflection:

```
object boxed = new KeyValuePair<int, int>(0, 0);
boxed.GetType()
     .GetField("key",
               BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public)
     .SetValue(boxed, 1);
Console.WriteLine(boxed); // [1, 0]
```

ILSpy показывает, что `unbox` тоже не генерируется.

Comment: Ахренеть ... Мне ещё учится и учится ! Спасибо буду пробовать.

Comment: @Aleksanders не расстраивайтесь , сам вопрос как и оба предложенных варианта решения это нечто из разряда "удивительное рядом" и в реальной разработке используется редко Видимо собеседовааший хотел просто потешить свое ЧСВ, а не нанять джуниора. На самом деле у джуниоров спрашивают менее экзотические вещи